# I'm trying to debug small mips code snippets in IDA with QEMU as debugger, but only NOP instructions show when I start the process

Tags: ida, disassembly, mips, qemu

I followed the tutorial [IDA Help: Debugging code snippets with QEMU](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1588.shtml).

It always worked with ARM code, but now I have to reverse some MIPS and only nops are displayed like this:

[image]

Should I adjust something on the memory map? As you can see, the code is rebased in the range of `0x8f0000000`.
Or is it something with the generated intermediate ELF file?

I am using the Mipsel_Malta config, cmd line is

`"D:\attila\qemu\bin\qemu-system-mipsel" -S -gdb tcp::%p,ipv4 -cpu 4Km -kernel "%e"`.

Comment: Seems like you haven't configured the gdb_arch.cfg properly

Comment: http://www.techbliss.org/threads/many-debuggers-for-ida-remote-gdb-with-qemu.94/

Comment: My gdb_arch.cfg _is_ in fact configured properly and according to the one discussed on the thread you linked, but thank you.

Comment: Last month i was reversing my router firmware and i had used this for setting up my MIPS debugging platform https://digital-forensics.sans.org/community/papers/grem/analyzing-backdoor-bot-mips-platform_2573

Comment: But anyway i will more than happy to look into your code if you are willing.